# The hello world pyscript demo is being stuck at somewhere forever, how do I do?

Tags: pyscript

I'm trying to run [pyscript](https://pyscript.net/)

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
  <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <py-script> print('Now you can!') </py-script>|
</body>

</html>
```

It is being stuck at somewhere forever.

[image]

Here is the console log though I don't get a clue about this issue.

[image]

What am I missing

Comment: Your program did not hang. It printed the message. Edit with details on what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you got the “|” ? It just because you typed “|” before the  tag